# I can't get userid from session?

Tags: php, authentication, session, userid

some help if you wish please for beginner user
will you please show me where is my code problem ?
i want to get user id from $_SESSION['userid']

but it's not working
i success to get username but not the id
i include session_start(); on each page to want to use it
but it's not showing the user id
only username working
here are my code

```
<?php
include("conn.php");

    // variable declaration
    $userid = "";
    $username = "";
    $email    = "";
    $errors   = array(); 
    $_SESSION['success'] = ""; 

    // call the login() function if register_btn is clicked
    if (isset($_POST['login_btn'])) {
        login();
    }


    if (isset($_GET['logout'])) {
        session_destroy();
        unset($_SESSION['user']);
        unset($_SESSION['username']);
        unset($_SESSION['userid']);
        unset($_SESSION['user_type']);
        header("location: ../login.php");
    }

    // return user array from their id
    function getUserById($id){
        global $conn;
        $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=" . $id;
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
        $user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        return $user;
    }


    // LOGIN USER
    function login(){
        global $conn, $username, $errors;

        // grap form values
        $username = e($_POST['username']);
        $password = e($_POST['password']);

        // make sure form is filled properly
        if (empty($username)) {
            array_push($errors, "Username is required");
        }
        if (empty($password)) {
            array_push($errors, "Password is required");
        }

        // attempt login if no errors on form
        if (count($errors) == 0) {
            $password = md5($password);


            $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password' LIMIT 1";
            $results = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
            if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) { // user found
            // Storing username in session variable 
                session_start(); 
                // check if user is admin or user
                $logged_in_user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results);
                $userid=$row['id'];
                $username=$row['username'];
                $user_type=$row['user_type'];
                $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                $_SESSION['userid'] = $userid; // <-this variable should now exist
                $_SESSION['user_type'] = $user_type;
                if ($logged_in_user['user_type'] == 'admin') {

                    $_SESSION['user'] = $logged_in_user;
                    $_SESSION['success']  = "You are now logged in";
                    header('location: admin/home.php');       
                }else{
                if ($logged_in_user['user_type'] == 'superuser') {

                    $_SESSION['user'] = $logged_in_user;
                    $_SESSION['success']  = "You are now logged in";
                    header('location: superuser/home.php');       
                }else{
                    $_SESSION['user'] = $logged_in_user;
                    $_SESSION['success']  = "You are now logged in";

                    header('location: index.php');
                }
        }   }else {
                array_push($errors, "Wrong username/password combination");
            }
        }
    }

    function isLoggedIn()
    {
        if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
    function isSuperuser()
    {
        if (isset($_SESSION['user']) && $_SESSION['user']['user_type'] == 'superuser' ) {
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
    function isAdmin()
    {
        if (isset($_SESSION['user']) && $_SESSION['user']['user_type'] == 'admin' ) {
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    // escape string
    function e($val){
        global $conn;
        return mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, trim($val));
    }

    function display_error() {
        global $errors;

        if (count($errors) > 0){
            echo '<div class="error">';
                foreach ($errors as $error){
                    echo $error .'<br>';
                }
            echo '</div>';
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: Note that your script has very common flaws that an attacker can use, such as [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php), the use of now insecure `md5`, trying to select the association of user and password to see if it exists (password should be checked separately).. You should probably read a little bit before you implement this in real conditions

Answer (score 0):

As far as i can tell, your script would run.
Though please note that when using with sessions and $_SESSION globals, you have to initialise it first by adding `session_start();` **at the top of your page.**

You should also dig into using PDO rather than mysqli or mysql.
I know this looks complicated, but it's the safest way to handle database queries.

Also don't use md5, use `password_hash();`

I also recommend adding `var_dump($row);` in this if statement, to see what data you are working with:
`if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) { // user found`

Comment: what i want is that if i echo $_SESSION['userid']; it give me logged in user id

Comment: @AbuErada then you have to store it like i did where that id is applied to the user.

Comment: i think you misunderstand my question , or am not understand your point

Comment: Yeah you edited your question, i'll edit my answer in a sec.

Comment: thanks' for your advise / i add session start(); as you and me say before but it's not working i don't know why so i ask for help from you..and by the way i will change the password encryption method after finishing my code ,

Comment: @AbuErada You have to start it ALL THE WAY at the top of your file.

Comment: yes i do that ---/ like these //session_start();
$addbyuser = $_SESSION['username'];  // username is ok but userid is not return when use $_SESSION['userid'];

Comment: @AbuErada use var_dump($row); so you can see if you are even getting an id.

Comment: @AbuErada You can also check you code to see if this session variable is not used or unset by another script, as all scripts that use session will share it

Comment: ok thanks i will, thank you, I am grateful for your advice